# Access attributes with beautifulSoup and print

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape a site to findall title attributes of h2 tag

```
     <h2 class="1"><a href="http://example.it/Titanic_Caprio.html" title="Titanic Caprio">Titanic_Caprio</a></h2>
```

Using this code, I'm accessing the entire h2 tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


url = "http://www.example.it"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
links = soup.findAll('h2')

print "".join([str(x) for x in links] )
```

using findAll('h2', attrs = {'title'}) doesn't have results. What Am I doing wrong? How can I print out the entire title's list in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `title` is not an attribute of the `h2` tag, but of a tag included in it. So you must first search for `<h2>` tags, and then subtags having a `title` attribute:

```
titles = []
h2_list = links = soup.findAll('h2')
for h2 in h2_list:
    titles.extend(h2.findAll(lambda x: x.has_attr('title')))
```

It works because BeautifulSoup can use functions as search filters.

Comment: works well! thank you for spending your time! Lambda is also a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass key value pairs in attrs

```
findAll('h2', attrs = {"key":"value"})
```

Comment: can have url that i can test